# Javascript breaks when using values from HTML input field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a grid of a specific height/width given input. If I hard code in the height and width in the canvas below (10 and 5 in this case) it works perfectly

```
const canvasWindow = document.getElementById("canvas-window")
const height = document.getElementById("height")
const width = document.getElementById("width")
const generateCanvasBtn = document.getElementById("generate-canvas-btn")

generateCanvasBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    const canvas = new Canvas(document.getElementById("canvas-window"), 10, 5);
    canvas.generateCanvas();
})
```

This example breaks though:

```
const canvasWindow = document.getElementById("canvas-window")
const height = document.getElementById("height")
const width = document.getElementById("width")
const generateCanvasBtn = document.getElementById("generate-canvas-btn")

generateCanvasBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const canvas = new Canvas(document.getElementById("canvas-window"), height.value, width.value);
    canvas.generateCanvas();
})
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? If I log height.value and width.value it is getting the values just fine, so I'm struggling to see how it's any different than being hardcoded if the values are being read in fine?
The error I'm getting is:

canvas.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')
at Canvas.generateCanvas (canvas.js:18:33)
at HTMLInputElement. (pixelcreator.js:8:12)

Here is code containing the line that the error references:

```
class Canvas {

grid;

constructor(window, height, width) {
    this.window = window;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
}

generateCanvas() {
    this.grid = new Array(this.height).fill(0).map(() => new Array(this.width).fill(0));
    for (let i = 0; i < this.height; i++) {
        const row = document.createElement("div");
        row.classList.add('row');
        this.window.appendChild(row);
        for (let j = 0; j < this.width; j++) {
            this.grid[i][j] = new Cell(row) // this is line 18 from the error
            this.grid[i][j].createCell();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height.value` or `width.value` might be a string type.

Try this:

```
new Canvas(document.getElementById("canvas-window"), parseInt(height.value), parseInt(width.value));
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution, quick question though- why was it able to use the "width" value correctly? It actually made a row of the correct width, but not the correct height before I used parseInt like you suggested.

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't think of any possibilities how it behaved so. Did you happen to use `<input type="number" ../>` for width?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the value of the input directly which is a string. Try parsing it to an integer with parseInt(...)

```js
const canvasWindow = document.getElementById("canvas-window")
const height = document.getElementById("height")
const width = document.getElementById("width")
const generateCanvasBtn = document.getElementById("generate-canvas-btn")

generateCanvasBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const canvas = new Canvas(document.getElementById("canvas-window"), parseInt(height.value), parseInt(width.value));
    canvas.generateCanvas();
})
```